# swift3 error : Argument labels '(configuration:, delegate:, delegateQueue:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: ios

I tried with following code but still same error.

```
 if let session = URLSession(configuration: defaultConfigObject!, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.mainQueue){

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Foundation` before `URLSession` as shown:

```
let session = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: defaultConfigObject!,
                                         delegate: self,
                                    delegateQueue: OperationQueue.mainQueue) {
    // ... //   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `queue` parameter also as below:-

```
if let session = URLSession(configuration: defaultConfigObject!, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main){
}
```

NSURLSessionDelegate official [documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLSession/sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:).

Comment: in swift 3 there is no `NS` is completely removed

Comment: Thank you for pointing you @Anbu.Karthik. I 've updated my answer. You always motivate me to correct my mistakes. Thank for being my mentor.

Comment: Thanks For your reply, but still i am getting following:
 errorArgument labels '(configuration:, delegate:, _:, queue:)' do not match any available overloads